# How to use contentURL in Research Kit to preform a online PDF file?

Tags: researchkit

I've been looking into source code of Research Kit Example called ORKTest:

```
if (type.integerValue == ORKConsentSectionTypeDataGathering) {
        /*
         Tests PDF content instead of text, HTML for Learn More.
         */
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SAMPLE_PDF_TEST" ofType:@"pdf"];
        consentSection.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

    }
```

It used a local PDF file path in .contentURL,and I'd like to replace it with a online PDF url such as http://examle.com/file/example.pdf

```
consentSection.contentURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("http://example.com/file/example.pdf")
```

or

```
    consentSection.contentURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("example.com/file/example.pdf")
```

but only got an empty page(the url that I used worked fine on browser,just a pdf file).

Anyone got any ideas,please?

Answer (score 0):

NSURL.fileURLWithPath only works with local files. You have to put it in app's sandbox, then ask `consentSection` to load it.

Comment: is there any way to directly show web pdf files by using  research kit?